# Unable to access a GCE in another subnet on same VPC over another NIC

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I have two GCEs in the same VPC but in different subnets. Both are GCEs are dual nic and everything is accessible over nic0.

```
VM-1
    nic0    172.16.132.4
    nic1    192.168.132.2
VM-2
    nic0    172.16.154.202
    nic1    192.168.154.202
```

However for nic1, I can't ping VM-2 from VM-1 on VPC-2.
The following doesn't work

```
ping 192.168.154.202 (doesn't work)
sudo ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8 (works!)
sudo ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8 (doesn't work!)
```

As per GCP guidance https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#routing-linux
I added what I believed is the requred routing:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.132.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 192.168.132.2 mtu 1430
echo "1 rt1" | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
sudo ip route add 192.168.132.1 src 192.168.132.2 dev eth1 table rt1
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.132.1 dev eth1 table rt1
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.132.2/16 table rt1
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.132.2/16  table rt1
```

Fw rules are all configured and should allow required ingress.
Running Rocky Linux.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you have multiple VPC’s because you have mentioned VPC-2 (“cant ping VM-2 from VM-1 on VPC-2”). Also could you please elaborate on your setup and if possible, please update the question with a Network Architecture diagram for the clear understanding. When I tried to replicate the issue I found that it is not possible to choose different subnets of the same VPC while creating network interfaces of the VM.

Comment: yes, nic0 is on on VPC-1 and nic1 is on VPC-2.
The point is, I can't communicate over nic1.

Comment: Hi Rubans, Thanks for the clarification. Please check on [Reverse Path Filtering](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.rpf.html) troubleshooting.